I am getting a permission error in my code , i am running the code in jupyter notebook and getting this error . Can anyone?
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[20], line 1
----> 1 train_features = extract_features(['images']) 

Cell In[12], line 4, in extract_features(images)
      2 features = []
      3 for image in tqdm(images):
----> 4     img = load_img(image,grayscale =  True )
      5     img = np.array(img)
      6     features.append(img)

File D:\Face Emotion Detection\venv\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\utils.py:113, in load_img(path, grayscale, color_mode, target_size, interpolation)
    110 if pil_image is None:
    111     raise ImportError('Could not import PIL.Image. '
    112                       'The use of `load_img` requires PIL.')
--> 113 with open(path, 'rb') as f:
    114     img = pil_image.open(io.BytesIO(f.read()))
    115     if color_mode == 'grayscale':
    116         # if image is not already an 8-bit, 16-bit or 32-bit grayscale image
    117         # convert it to an 8-bit grayscale image.

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'images'

Getting this while running this
train_features = extract_features(['images'])

I was expecting it train my model using this data set that i get from kaggle for facial emotion detection

Your image is a folder, provide the correct path.
